# RPM build executable '/usr/bin/rpmbuild' not found on this system (mac)

Tags: java, maven, git-bash, rpm

Im trying to install maven dependencies through the command 'mvn clean install' in gitbash. I get this error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmpyd.png)

Is anyone familiar with rpm on mac? I have tried to install rpm through homebrew, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Without more details on what you're building, we can't really help you. It sounds like the Maven build you're running contains Linux-specific parts (RPM is a Linux package manager), so it won't run on MacOS.

Comment: @mark Yes, there is som Linux specific parts. So there is not any options to fix this?

Comment: That depends, show us the POM and explain to us what the build is supposed to do, maybe a solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

`rpmbuild` is a Red Hat Linux family specific tool for building RPMs - packages of applications.

It looks like during the build process you have maven plugin that calls thos `rpmbuild` tool that is obviously is not present on Mac.

Now, you can use maven profiles by os so that this plugin won't be invoked at all on macos.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>linux</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          ...  <!-- here comes your rpm plugin --> 
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

You might also be required to enclose some other plugins that maybe use the RPM generated during this step... It really depends on your project, hopefully it won't be an obstacle to development process of the project (I assume that you're trying to compile stuff, run test, and do some development tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install rpm on your Mac system for this to work.

Run the below command in the terminal:

```
 brew install rpm
```

This will install the rpmbuild for your MacOS.
Although the build will still fail when running from IntelliJ [It is for me as this will install rpmbuild in /usr/local/bin and not in /usr/local].

However, you can then proceed to run the maven command from the terminal [IntelliJ, gitbash or otherwise]